# An EAGAIN error when writing from kernel to user space app

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netlink

I have this issue, that happens once in a while for no clear reason:
I have kernel module, that sends messages to user space deamon application using genlmsg_unicast().
After some time, all messages start to fail and the error code is -11 (EAGAIN).
And there's no way to get out of this.
Even if I restart the user application. Also, I don't see any error on the receiving side in the application. It just stops receiving packets.
Can somebody advise?

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: seems like you are filling up the buffer queue even before the userspace has consumed it. you need to either increase the buffer size or do a handshake with kernel/userpace.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: What do you mean "do a handshake"?

Comment: notify the kernel from userspace you have read the buffer so that you can fill in a new one.

Comment: The question is, why doesn't the queue get cleaned up once I restart the user space application?